# Is there a way to permanently change all the decimals in AutoCAD to 2?

Tags: autocad

For example

1.5678

I would like to change to

1.57

Permanently, meaning that every time I open another project, all the digits are in 2 decimal places only.

is there a way to make it like that?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the version of autocad you are using you can go to Dimension styles, and set the precision of the Angular And linear dimensions.

[image]

In a user document that can be modified by the DIMSTYLE.